# iterating over DbSet<TEntity> vs IQueryable<out T>

Tags: entity-framework

Using Entity Framework I select some data from a table and iterate over it with `foreach` loop. I am wondering when is the data getting queried in the following examples?

Example 1.

```
var countries = db.WorldCountries;
foreach(var item in countries)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Country: {0}", item.Country);
}
```

Example 2.

```
var countries = db.WorldCountries.Where(t => t.Country == "Country Name");
foreach(var item in countries)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Country: {0}", item.Country);
}
```

In the first example, `countries` is `DbSet<WorldCountries>` In the second example, `countries` is `IQueryable<out WorldCountries>`.

Without the `.ToList()` in the above examples how is the data retrieved? Is the entire data set retrieved when the `foreach` loop starts (as if `.ToList()` were called at the beginning of the first iteration) or queries are issued to the database on each iteration of the loop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In both examples, the `IQueryable<WorldCountries>` is compiled to SQL and executed at the point you enter `foreach` (when `foreach` calls `GetEnumerator`). So you receive the result from the db just before the first iteration, not piece by piece on every single iteration.(The results come via a DataReader so actual data transfer may be done piece by piece for each iteration but what I mean is, there is not a separate SQL query on each iteration).

Note that `DbSet<T>` also implements `IQueryable<WorldCountries>`, so your both examples work the same, except the second one happens to include a where clause.

When you add `.ToList`, that iterates through and fills up a list before returning, so in that case you transfer all the necessary data from the db before moving on to the next statement.

Comment: Are you sure that the data transfer is done piece by piece, if so do you have any references on that?  I am very curious about this

Comment: I was able to confirm that you are correct, it does indeed pull the data in batches, not all at once. I wrote a test by iterating through a large dbset - part way through i kill that db connection, and as expected an error was thrown.

Comment: This is an old but good bit of info. I just ran into the piece-by-piece bit in that an update was happening inside the loop, causing EF to throw the following error: `System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.`.