# entity .ToList() generates a System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity

I have a table with half a million rows. I need to update every single row but the ToList() fails:

```
List<Contacts> allContacts = objDatabase.Contacts.ToList();
```

I get a System.OutOfMemoryException every time. Is there a way around this?

I already have the App.Config workaround but still no go:

```
<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
```

I'm on a 64bit machine with 8GB of RAM

Comment: Why do you need all those 500,000 records at once ? Try to get them in chunks, process them and get another chunk.

Comment: Have you tried enumerating the items one by one using a `foreach` loop so you're streaming them one by one from the database? Either way, 500,00 items is quite a lot to deal with in one go when using an ORM.

Comment: Even though you're on a 64-bit machine, you may be running in a 32-bit process.  Some project templates have the default platform target as x86, or have the "Prefer 32-bit" option enabled.  If you *are* running in a 62-bit process, running out of physical memory doesn't cause an out-of-memory exception; the memory gets paged to the disk which generally results in terrible performance.

Comment: Grab the list in chunks, as @brz suggested. Use Skip() and Take(), and after each chuck, make sure to dispose of and create a new entity container so your memory doesn't get used up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using chunking.  It will dispose of the container (and the downloaded entities) after every chunk.  Memory should be released by the GC long before your system runs out of memory.

```
int chunkSize = 50;
int curCount = 0;

while (true)
{
    using (var db = new DbEntities())
    {
        var chunk = db.Contacts.Skip(curCount).Take(chunkSize).ToArray();
        curCount += chunkSize;

        if (chunk.Length == 0) break;

        foreach (var contact in chunk)
        {
            //do any work for the contact here
            contact.Something = "SomethingNew";
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Feel free to play around with the chunk size.  The larger the chunk, the faster the entire process should be, but it will use up more memory.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the only way to go. Kinda weird that .NET cannot handle half a million rows, this is 2014..

Comment: I had to add an order by before calling skip.  other than that it works perfect!

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
IEnumerable<Contacts> allContacts = objDatabase.Contacts.AsEnumerable();
```

Never convert allContacts to a list. Just use is like an enumerator and apply Foreach loop to access each contacts.

Comment: This is good but now the same exception occurs in the SaveChanges(), I guess I will have to split the processing into chunks like the other proposed

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: ok. got it now. I don't like chunky solution but it seem that's the only way for now.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
foreach (Contacts c in objDatabase.Contacts) c.value = newvalue;
```

Comment: This would still result in every possible record being downloaded to local memory.

Comment: A Nathen.  BS.  That is one record at a time.  That is how IEnumerable works.

Comment: Do you research.  Once the foreach begins, the ENTIRE result set is is pulled from the DB: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18216387/2465182.  This would result in just as much memory usage as a ToList().

Comment: @NathanA Double BS  Did you read that answer?  It uses a DataReader that pulls results one at a time (and holds the connection).  That is not the same as foreash does not begin until the ENTIRE result set is is pulled from the DB.  You consume them one at a time and they go out of memory.

Comment: Exception now occurs in the SaveChanges(), time to split the processing into chunks...

Comment: Why not use a datareader and a command?  Better yet use a single update command.