# Entity SaveChanges generates a System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, .net, database, linq, entity

I have a process that gets chunks of data then updates and saves them

The process is per chunk of 50K records (total is around 400K) but I always get a System.OutOfMemoryException about half way (when the process memory hits 1.4GB)

```
IEnumerable<Contacts> allContacts = objDB.Contacts.OrderBy(p=>p.Period).AsEnumerable();

int chunkSize = 50000;
int curCount = 0;

while (true)
{
    var chunk = allContacts.Skip(curCount).Take(chunkSize).AsEnumerable();
    curCount += chunkSize;

    int count = chunk.Count();
    if (count == 0) break;

    UpdateContacts(chunk);

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

I tried forcing the Garbage Collector, creating a new context after each SaveChanges, adding the gcAllowVeryLargeObjects key in the .config still no go

Any ideas?

The UpdateContacts() is nothing special:

```
private void UpdateContacts(IEnumerable<Contacts> allContacts)
{
    foreach (Contact contact in allContacts)
    {
        //update stuff here
    }

    objDB.SaveChanges();
    objDB = new DBContext(); 
}
```

Comment: Any chance we could see UpdateContacts()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [entity .ToList() generates a System.OutOfMemoryException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900285/entity-tolist-generates-a-system-outofmemoryexception)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up generating UPDATE SQL statements instead and also only specifying the columns I need in the first line using Select(...)