# Remove/adding from virtual collections memory usage

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, out-of-memory, entity-framework-6

From what I can tell when profiling the sql, it executes a sql statement to retrieve all users for the group when it calls `group.Users.Remove(user)`. Users is a virtual collection on the group, using Entity Framework 6 code first.

```
var usersToRemove = Context.users.Where(u=>someListOfIds.Contains(u.Id)); //might only be a few users

foreach(var group in Context.groups)
{
    foreach(var user in usersToRemove.Where(u=>u.groupId == group.Id)){
        group.Users.Remove(user);//group.Users might have millions of users, do all users get pulled back into memory at this point?
    }
}
```

My question is, do all the groups Users get loaded into memory when removing and item from the collection here `group.Users.Remove(user)`?

Comment: You statement `Context.groups.where...` results in an `IQueryable` that is going to get resolved when you start looping over `groupsToRemove` In addition, unless you're dealing with millions of users, resolving the whole query isn't going to run you into a memory problem (and would be slightly faster than resolving each one as you loop over the collection).

Comment: This is currently running as a hangfire job, asynchronously.  Speed isn't as much of an issue as is memory constraint.  There is going to be a large number of users, millions, and this can most definitely be an issue.  Are you saying that as soon as you start iterating through groups, all the groups are loaded into memory?

Comment: modified the comment to be do all users get pulled back into memory - that probably confused some people

Comment: I think it's not. It's just remove the user by the primary key. But you can easilly debug this. :)

Comment: debugging will sometimes force it to load all the items into memory, so i can't be too sure it would behave the same way when not in debug mode.

Comment: @JustinBicknell: Based on my testing, using SQL Profiler, yes, as soon as you start to iterate over the `IQueryable` it issues a statement to the database that pulls back the entire result set. Whether it actually instantiates all the entities at that point I'm not sure.

Comment: @CraigW. I see the same thing in sql profiler - however - i'm not sure if that pulls the entire result set into memory, or acts like a data reader where it can pull each record one at a time

Comment: IIRC a DataReader uses a cursor to accomplish that (it's been a while since I wrote raw ADO.NET). This wasn't creating a cursor.

Comment: interesting - ok - thanks for that

Comment: @CraigW. - see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216226/iterating-over-dbsettentity-vs-iqueryableout-t

It suggests that the actual data transfer might still be done piece by piece

Comment: I was wrong about the DataReader. I had a few minutes to throw a test together and it did not create a cursor on the server. The only way to know for sure would be to run something like WireShark and actually watch the network traffic between your application and the server. The other thing you could try is pull your network connection after the first iteration and see if it continues to run.

Comment: @CraigW - i was able to confirm that killing the connection to the db part way through the loop does indeed throw an error which suggests it pulls it in batches and not all at once. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do all the users.Groups get loaded into memory when removing and item from the collection here user.Groups.Remove(group)?

Yes, I think that invoking `group.Users` *would* load all the users. Invoking `context.Users` (or `context.Groups`) would return an `IQueryable` (because `Users` and `Groups` are `DbSets`), whereas `groups.Users` is presumably an `ICollection<User>`. So (assuming you have lazy loading enabled, etc.) it will be populated when you access it.